# Form data not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

Can anyone tell me why my data will not insert into my database? The connect info is good. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
error_reporting();
include('include/config.php');
$strMsg="Signup, It's Free!";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try This Fecal Matter</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    function validate($strMsg){
        //Validation upon Submit Click
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            //Validate First Name Field
                if($_POST['fName']==""){
                    $strMsg="Please Enter Your First Name.";
                    showMForm($strMsg);
                }
            //Validate Last Name Field
                elseif($_POST['lName']==""){
                    $strMsg="Please Enter Your Last Name.";
                    showMForm($strMsg);
                }
            //elseif for validation of Email with a Regular Expression
                elseif(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_POST['eMail'])) {
                    $strMsg="Please Enter Your Email.";
                    showMForm($strMsg);
                }

            //Validate password
                elseif($_POST['pWord1']==""){
                    $strMsg="Please Enter A Password.";
                    showMForm($strMsg);
                }
                elseif($_POST['pWord2']!=$_POST['pWord1']){
                    $strMsg="Your Passowrds Do Not Match.";
                    showMForm($strMsg);
                }
else{

    $fName=$_POST['fName'];
    $lName=$_POST['lName'];
    $eMail=$_POST['eMail'];
    $pass=md5($_POST['pWord1']);




        /*$SQL="SELECT eMail FROM users WHERE eMail = '".$eMail."'";
                $rs = mysql_query($SQL);
echo $SQL;
            if($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){
                            $strMsg="Email Already Registered";
                            showForm($strMsg);
                }
            else{
    */
    //Send Content To Database..
//      $SQL = "INSERT INTO 'users' (`userID`, `fName`, `lName`, `eMail`, `pass`)    
VALUES (NULL,
    dbConnect();
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO users (`userID`, `fName`, `lName`, `eMail`, `pass`,    
`bgPic`,`bio`) VALUES (NULL,'$fName', '$lName', '$eMail', '$pass', NULL, NULL );";
            echo $fName."<br/>";
            echo $lName."<br/>";
            echo $eMail."<br/>";
            echo $pass."<br/>";
            //  }
                echo $SQL;
}
}
else
    showMForm($strMsg);

}






    function showMForm($strMsg){
        echo"<div id=\"form\">\n";
        echo"<h2>".$strMsg."</h2><br/>\n";
        echo" <form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\" >\n";
        echo"                   <p>First Name:<br/>\n";
        echo"                   <input type=\"text\" name=\"fName\" value=\"".$_POST['fName']."\"/></p>\n";
        echo"                   <p>Last Name:<br/>\n";
        echo"                   <input type=\"text\" name=\"lName\" value=\"".$_POST['lName']."\"/></p>\n";
        echo"                   <p>E-mail:<br/>\n";
        echo"                   <input type=\"text\" name=\"eMail\" value=\"".$_POST['eMail']."\"/></p>\n";
        echo"                   <p>Passwod:<br/>\n";
        echo"                   <input type=\"text\" name=\"pWord1\" value=\"\"/></p>\n";
        echo"                   <p>Re-Enter Passwod:<br/>\n";
        echo"                   <input type=\"text\" name=\"pWord2\" value=\"\"/></p>\n";   
        echo"                   <p>Regarding:<br/>\n";
        echo"                       <select name=\"state\">\n";
        echo"                           <option value=\"Ohio\">Ohio</option>\n";
        echo"                           <option value=\"Michigan\">Michigan</option>\n";
        echo"                           <option value=\"Indiana\">Indiana</option>\n";
        echo"                           <option value=\"Pensylvania\">Pensylvania</option>\n";
        echo"                       </select>\n";
        echo"                   <p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"btnSubmit\" name=\"submit\" /></p>\n";
        echo" </form>\n";
}

        validate($strMsg);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. the ereg functions are deprecated. 2. the mysql functions are deprecated. 3. you're utterly vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) attacks. 4. You're not actually doing any queries, since they're all commented out. 5. you have no error handling on the queries, so you'd never be able to retrieve the error messages that help you diagnose problems.

Comment: apart from that ^^^^^^ its all good :-)

Comment: I guess semi-colon at the end of the query statement is the problem, try removing it out and see..

Comment: If your question is answered, mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you commented out your **SQL Queries**

**ex:**

```
   //Send Content To Database..
//      $SQL = "INSERT INTO 'users' (`userID`, `fName`, `lName`, `eMail`, `pass`)    
VALUES (NULL,
    dbConnect();
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO users (`userID`, `fName`, `lName`, `eMail`, `pass`,    
`bgPic`,`bio`) VALUES (NULL,'$fName', '$lName', '$eMail', '$pass', NULL, NULL );";
            echo $fName."<br/>";
            echo $lName."<br/>";
            echo $eMail."<br/>";
            echo $pass."<br/>";
            //  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend you have not used `mysql_query()` function. Where is it?

```
mysql_query($SQL);
```

and you are done.

Comment: if your problem is solved then mark answer as solved, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query($sql);` is what you're missing...but just as important, you're also missing the part where you sanitize your input before the query.

To do that use: `mysql_real_escape_string($value);`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in this code

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO users (`userID`, `fName`, `lName`, `eMail`, `pass`,    
`bgPic`,`bio`) VALUES (NULL,'$fName', '$lName', '$eMail', '$pass', NULL, NULL );
```

To :

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO users ( `fName`, `lName`, `eMail`, `pass`,) VALUES ('$fName', '$lName', '$eMail', '$pass');
```

the problem maybe userID on database mysql is primary key ?

i hope this work